# Can I use input checked to initiate CSS which highlight an image?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I have a safety form that I'd like to highlight part of an image when an input is checked. I was able to make part of the image highlight with a hover but I can't seem to do it with CSS using Checked. Any ideas what I'm missing? If I switch the css tropic:checked to hover then it will highlight my selection. The problem is I can't get the same functionality via checked. Is it possible?

Thanks!

```
<style>
.check-with-label:checked ~ .product-add-image-preview {
 position: absolute;
content: '';
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
pointer-events: none;

}

.circle-with-label:checked ~ .add-head {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid #aaa; /*To show the boundaries of the element*/
}
.circle-with-label:checked ~ .add-head {
position: absolute;
content: '';
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
pointer-events: none;
}
.trPic{ 
width:320px; 
height:700px; 
background: url(<?php echo base_url('uploads/front_body.png'); ?>) no-repeat; 
border:5px solid #000000; } 
.trPic .head{ 
position:relative; 
top:10px; 
left:100px;
width:60px; 
height:30px; 
background:#FF2400; 
opacity:0; } 
.trPic:checked .head { 
opacity:0.7; }

</style>
```

```
<div align="center">

<?php if( !function_exists('form_open')): ?>
    <?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>
<?php endif;?>

<?php echo form_open(current_url(),array('id'=>'form')); ?>


        <?php echo form_label('Head','head'); ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name ="head" id="head" class="head" value="1"/>       
        <?php echo form_label('Face','face'); ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name ="face" id="check_1" class="check-with-label" value="1" />


        <?php echo form_fieldset_close(); ?>

    <br />

<br />
<br />
<br />
<?php echo form_button(array('name'=>'submit','type'=>'submit','value'=>1,'content'=>'Submit')); ?>

</div>
<div class ="trPic">
<div class="head">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery and call addClass () adding the class that contains the styling you want on the event where the box gets checked.

Comment: answers should be code,not just  you could use X and do Y

Comment: Sorry, I put it where I can, but sometimes I'm on my phone when I answer. I don't mind giving an answer that points someone in the right direction if I think they aren't even aware of the existence of the solution at all and could google it and work it out themselves if they were just pointed in the right direction. So, I try to give code when and where I can but I don't feel it's always 100% necessary.

Comment: Maybe this should be a comment instead.